# different accuracy in Tensorflow saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have managed to train a CNN model in Tensorflow which the input is 1D ECG signals of sick and healthy patients. The architecture is composed of CNN-Max pooling-CNN-Max pooling-CNN-Max pooling-CNN-Max pooling-Fully connected-Fully connected-Softmax.

I used this code for defining the cost function and training the network:

```
# How we train
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Just initialize
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Define accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),
                              tf.argmax(y_,1),name='correct_pred')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(
           correct_prediction, "float"),name='accuracy')

#%% Actually train

train= np.reshape(train,[-1,length,1])
test= np.reshape(test,[-1,length,1])
epochs = 200
train_acc = np.zeros(epochs//10)
test_acc = np.zeros(epochs//10)
start_time = time.time()
for i in tqdm(range(epochs), ascii=True):
    # Record summary data, and the accuracy
    if (i+1) % 10 == 0:  
        # Check accuracy on train set
        TRA = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: train,
            y_: onehot_train, keep_prob: 0.75})
        train_acc[i//10] = TRA
        # And now the validation set
        TEA = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test,
            y_: onehot_test, keep_prob: 0.75})
        test_acc[i//10] = TEA
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (i+1), ", Train accuracy=", "{:.9f}".format(TRA),
              ", Test accuracy=", "{:.9f}".format(TEA),"--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        start_time = time.time()
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: train,\
        y_: onehot_train, keep_prob: 0.75})
```

after 200 epochs the accuracy of model reaches about 95 percent.

[image]

After training I saved my model like this

```
#%% Save the weights
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saved_path=saver.save(sess , 'SavedModel/SCD')
```

But when I use the saved model for evaluating the accuracy with exactly the train data, It shows a 54 percent accuracy. i can't figure out what's the problem.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time as time
from scipy import stats
import math
tf.set_random_seed(1)

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('SCD.meta')
sess=tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X =graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")
Y=graph.get_tensor_by_name("labels:0")
accuracy=graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy:0")
keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name("keep_prob:0")
dropout=0.75
batch_accuracy=sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={X: train, Y: onehot_train, keep_prob: dropout})
```

Which the batch_accuracy is 0.54370368. why the accuracy in saved model is different from the main trained model?

Comment: Why are you using dropout during evaluation, it should be set to `1.0` during testing. Dropout will randomly set a fraction of the features to `0`, that's why the performance degrades.

Comment: you mean I should set dropout to ``1.0``?

Comment: Doesn't it make problem to train the model with dropout equal to  ``0.75`` and test it with a different value?

Comment: Dropout should always be set to `1.0` during testing, irrespective of the value you use during training.

Comment: I set it to ``1.0`` but the accuracy didn't change.